# scipy interp1d extrapolation method

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, extrapolation

I am trying to extrapolate values from some endpoints as shown in the image below

[extrapolated value illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4xO5.png)

I have tried using the scipy interp1d method as shown below

```
from scipy import interpolate

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0,1,2,0]

f = interpolate.interp1d(x,y,fill_value='extrapolate')

print(f(4.3))
```

output : -0.5999999999999996

Though this is correct, I also need a second extrapolated value which is the intersection of X on segment i=1.The estimated value i am expecting is ~ 3.3 as seen from the graph in the image above.But I need get this programmatically,I am hoping there should be a way of returning multiple values from interp1d(.....) or something. Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extrapolate based all but the last pair of values, you can just build a second interpolator, using `x[:-1], y[:-1])`